# How to get number of steps to get a sub of tree

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I do to get number of steps to get a sub of tree .

for example I have a table like this:

```
id    title      parent_id
1       A           0
2       B           0
3       C           1
4       F           3
5       O           3
6       D           2
7       J           6
8       T           2
9       P           8


A   // 1 step
   C   //2 step
      F   //3 step
      O   //3 step

B   //1 step
  D  //2 step
    J  //3 step
  T  //2 step
    P  //3 step
```

for example if I give a number like 1 (`id` = 1 ), it should return 1 and id=6 it should return 2 as step.

my DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `Recursive CTE`. This can be done easily through `Recursive CTE`

Answer (score 0):

It can be a recursive stored procedure, if your tree is not very deep. Something like this (with addition of proper condition handlers), or anything of the same kind, it can be written in various ways:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE depth(IN n INT, OUT depth INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE parent INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth=255;
    SELECT parent_id INTO parent FROM t WHERE id=n;
    IF parent = 0 THEN SET depth = 1;
    ELSE CALL depth(parent,depth); SET depth = depth + 1;
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;

CALL(6,@depth);
SELECT @depth;
```

Also, MariaDB 10.2 supports recursive CTE. It's an early beta now, so it's not good for production, but if you're only evaluating your options, you can try it out. This should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree(id,parent_id,depth) AS 
  ( 
    SELECT id, parent_id, 1 from t WHERE parent_id=0 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, depth+1 FROM t JOIN tree ON tree.id = t.parent_id
  ) SELECT * FROM tree WHERE id = 6;
```